# Parse XML : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

Just as learning efforts, I have been trying to parse a simple XML file in my test code, but can't seem to work it out.

Error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load...
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

It would be a great help if someone can spread some light, and what can be done.

**here is the sample**

```
    var xmlhttp;
    var url = "https://someCDNAddress/xyz.xml";
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Pasrse XML to DOM
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

Comment: That error is telling you that the website you're trying to source the XML from is not configured to allow you to do that from code in a browser. Browsers will not let code running for one domain to access content from another domain unless the other domain explicitly allows it, and that one doesn't.

Comment: are you trying in a remote server or with file:// path?

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: @Pointy: wow, thanks, yes you are right. That's the issue. But I need to find the solution. Maybe then I can just parse it from local file.

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil: I am trying simply trying the code on my local machine, and testing in Chrome.

Comment: @Indigo you may be able to do that, or set the file up on your own local HTTP server. You can fetch the content from *outside* a browser of course, or just fetch it with your browser and do a "Save As ..." into a file.

Comment: my advice try with http protocol

Comment: @Pointy: Yes, I think, I will go for local HTTP server and just use saved files for testing.